# Custom module with config exposed in json api

Tags: configuration, 8

I have a module with two pieces of config set using an admin form and Drupal the drupal config service.

Like this

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

    $this->config('mars_spot_collection.defaultcollections')
      ->set('default_collection_title', $form_state->getValue('default_collection_title'))
      ->set('default_collection_description', $form_state->getValue('default_collection_description'))
      ->save();
  }
```

How do I make this conig available in the JSONAPI?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it. Not with the core JSON:API module. Out of the box, the resources JSON:API exposes are all the entity definitions from [`EntityTypeManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityTypeManager.php/class/EntityTypeManager/9.0.x) which includes content & config entities (defined by extending `ConfigEntityBase`).

However, arbitrarily set config values will not be exposed. JSON:API also doesn't support custom resources, as JSON:API [docs state](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21jsonapi%21jsonapi.api.php/group/jsonapi_architecture/9.0.x#api):

> The JSON:API module provides *no PHP API to modify its behavior.* It
> is designed to have zero configuration.
>
> • Adding new resources/resource types is unsupported: all
> entities/entity types are exposed automatically. If you want to expose
> more data via the JSON:API module, the data must be defined as entity.
> See the "Resources" section.

The [JSON:API Resources](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources) project attempts to fill this in if you want to design your own endpoint with custom responses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was curious why image styles were available in the json API and looked at the source code. It seems they're entity types that extend ConfigEntityBase so I think the answer needs adjusting as config entities are available in the json API. In my question I wasn't using config entities but the config factory which I don't think uses entites.

Comment: Updated. I remember mentioning that in the first draft but I think it got lost as I wanted to mention you can't control JSON:API to dump arbitrary data. Feel free to edit if you see something else missing.